# I developed next.js and tailwind css app. It runs perfectly well on vs code, without any errors or warnings but it won't deploy on vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

The app wouldn't deploy and it's giving the same exact 4 errors on vercel. I can't idenify where the problem is because there are no errors or warnings on vs code

I tried overriding the settings on the project settings but it did not work. The project is in the master branch in my github repo, should it necessarily be in the main branch for it to deploy successfully?Here's the error

```
[20:10:08.596] Running build in Cleveland, USA (East) – cle1
[20:10:08.661] Cloning github.com/Muriithi-ui/JohnMuriithiPortfolio (Branch: master, Commit: 5b19ba2)
[20:10:09.145] Previous build caches not available
[20:10:16.181] Cloning completed: 7.520s
[20:10:16.376] Running "vercel build"
[20:10:16.831] Vercel CLI 29.0.3
[20:10:17.079] Installing dependencies...
[20:10:19.732] npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
[20:10:19.782] npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
[20:10:21.244] npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@3.0.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
[20:10:32.987] 
[20:10:32.987] added 455 packages in 16s
[20:10:32.987] 
[20:10:32.988] 126 packages are looking for funding
[20:10:32.988]   run `npm fund` for details
[20:10:33.008] Detected Next.js version: 13.3.1
[20:10:33.011] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[20:10:33.012] Running "npm run build"
[20:10:33.323] 
[20:10:33.323] > myreact-portfolio@0.1.0 build
[20:10:33.323] > next build
[20:10:33.323] 
[20:10:33.740] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[20:10:33.741] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[20:10:33.741] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[20:10:33.741] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[20:10:33.741] 
[20:10:33.870] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[20:10:35.377] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
[20:10:38.235] Failed to compile.
[20:10:38.235] 
[20:10:38.235] ./pages/index.js
[20:10:38.235] Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/bigj4.jpg'
[20:10:38.235] 
[20:10:38.235] https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[20:10:38.236] 
[20:10:38.236] 
[20:10:38.236] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[20:10:38.275] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[20:10:38.956] Deployment completed
[20:10:38.575] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

?